# Tizen - Overlap app UI over lock screen

Tags: alarm, lockscreen, tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm currently building a native app on Tizen latest SDK and it needs to be programmed in C language. 
In my app I need to build a kind of "alarm clock" that will go off in a certain time and if the device is asleep my app will need to woke it up. I can do this already but my app is not shown in the lock screen. I want to know if you guys have any idea of how I can wake up the screen AND make my app ui's go overlapping the lock screen natively and in using the new SDK that it is C based.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, Tizen Native API is in C++, not C.

As for your question, on [https://developer.tizen.org/](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.native.appprogramming/html/guide/shell/lock_screen.htm) you can find examples:

how to show popup on locked screen:

```
Popup pPopup = new (std::nothrow) Popup();
pPopup->Construct(true, Dimension(600, 750));

if (Tizen::Shell::LockManager::GetInstance()->IsLocked())
{
   // 'http://tizen.org/privilege/uimanager' platform privilege required
   pPopup->SetZOrderGroup(WINDOW_Z_ORDER_GROUP_HIGHEST);
}
```

how to unlock screen:

```
if (Tizen::Shell::LockManager::GetInstance()->IsLocked())
{
   // 'http://tizen.org/privilege/lockmanager' platform privilege required
   Tizen::Shell::LockManager::GetInstance()->Unlock();
   UiApp::GetInstance()->GetFrameAt(0)->SetZOrderGroup(WINDOW_Z_ORDER_GROUP_NORMAL);
}
```

Comment: M.wasowski, the new API is in C as I said in the question and I have this examples. But thank you for trying to help.

Comment: OK, I found capi in SDK beta and see what do you mean (I didn't know it has published already). For your use case I would see notification capi; you can make notification appear on lockscreen, you can add sound to it, you can also specify action via app-control, so you have all the tools you need.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about using notifications but I just wanted to make sure about the other way wasn't possible :/ Thank you for the tip.